# Setup Neo4j with Apache Tomcat's JDBCRealm

Tags: tomcat, neo4j, jdbcrealm

We are trying to use the JDBCRealm to authenticate users with the neo4j database.
We followed all the steps in the JDBCRealm documentation and we think that neo4j is not supported.

When trying to authenticate a user it sends queries that aren't in the cypher language.
For example, we get:

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error executing cypher statement(s) [{code=Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax, message=Invalid input 'L': expected 't/T' (line 1, column 3 (offset: 2))
"SELECT user_pass FROM users WHERE user_name = {1}"
   ^}]`

The error occurs when filling the HTTP BASIC authentication form and submitting.

Details:

1. We added the JDBCRealm to the tomcat server.xml
2. We added user authentication to all our web apps pages in the web.xml file
3. We use BASIC authentication

Might neo4j not even be supported for JDBCRealm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use JDBCRealm with Neo4j. The reason is that JDBCRealm builds an SQL statement under the hoods depending on your config (tablename, columns, etc.).

The JDBC driver for Neo4j is "just" a transport layer for Cypher, therefore you cannot send SQL.

I can think of creating a `CypherRealm` for tomcat that emits then something like `MATCH (u:User{name:{name}}) RETURN u`.

Comment: Is neo4j even designed to support usernames/passwords data?

Comment: Sure, they are just provided to the server or in JDBC to the driver.

Answer (score 0):

**In General, you need to differentiate between JDBCRealms!** 
Some Realms are using quite static SQL, e.g. configurable are only the values like username, password, db-url, but some of them are flexible enough to include custom SQL or, and this is **quite useful in your case, even CQL**.

We used to configure authentication and authorization by Tomcat Realms for a long time. We switched to Apache Shiro and use the Shiro Realm org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm , configured in the shiro.ini

**Shiro accepts flexible configuration with your own CQL for**

1. user
2. role
3. permission (optional)

Here is an example how to **setup Tomcat and shiro.ini**

**1) Set JNDI Resource in your webapp context.xml**

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver" maxIdle="30" maxTotal="50" maxWaitMillis="10000" 
            name="jdbc/SomeJndiNameForYourNeo4jDbResource" url="jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost" type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="neo4j" password="neo4j"/>
```

**2) Get that JNDI-Object inside shiro.ini**

```
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.resourceName = java:comp/env/jdbc/SomeJndiNameForYourNeo4jDbResource

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = MATCH (u:User{email:?}) RETURN u.password
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = MATCH (u:User{email:?})-[hr:HAS_ROLE]->(r:Role) RETURN r.name
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = MATCH (:User{email:?})-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->(p:Permission) RETURN p.name

jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher
jdbcRealm.dataSource=$ds
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
```

*-> passwordMatcher needs to be configured as well! Check Apache Shiro documentation*